# Views in Layout Not Getting Created Properly

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, layout

Recently, I came across an issue with my layout files. Whenever I click enter to add a view in an .xml file like so:

[image]

And then when I click enter:

[image]

As you can see it did not generate the attributes like 'layout_width' and 'layout_height' etc. 
This problem only happened after connecting my Git account to Android Studio.

**This issue is only in the 'Text' tab of the layout file, so the 'design' tab works fine**

*I have 'Invalidated Caches & Restarted' but that didn't work.*

**EDIT: I opened up another project and added a view throughout the text tab and it worked - the working project is not connected to Git.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `gradle.build (Module:app)`. My target SDK version was set to 26 which it gave a warning about compatibility issues. So after changing it to 28 and syncing my project the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this steps below**

1 Sync your project (If it's doesn't work) try this below

2 Invalidated Caches & Restarted

3 Restart Your System or Android Studio

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Everything is fine on another project, there just seems to be something up with this one specifically. I have connected the problematic project with Git, if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

What's your android version?. maybe that's a bug in that android studio version please try updating studio.